# While для удаления нескольких строк

Tags: while, php

Доброго всем здравия!
Я программист на pascal (там понятнее цикл while), а в php самоучка и до сих пор многое понять не могу.
Вот есть два значения первая запись **$first`_`id`_`rec** и последняя **$last`_`id`_`rec**
Делаю сравнение While и код срабатывает, но один раз и всё зависает в "504 Gateway Time-out"

```
    do
    {
        mysql_query ("DELETE FROM $userstable WHERE `ID` =('$first_id_rec');", $db);
    }
    while (($first_id_rec+7) < $last_id_rec);
```

Что в этой конструкции не так?
Ведь условие простое - "*делать удаление первой_строки пока №_первой_строки+7 < №_последней*".
(P.S. почему в php так всё сложно-то!)

Comment: @DreamChild  
Совершенно верно!!! Я просто при повторном пошаговом просмотре кода уже это понял!

Comment: Тогда вам осталось поразмыслить над удалением из БД в цикле и почитать о SQL. Начните с [BETWEEN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp), например.

Comment: php не сложнее паскаля, я вас уверяю. А вообще, извините, конечно, за вопрос,но как вас угораздило до php докатиться?

Comment: А на чём кодить web-приложения надо?
Pithon учить? опять всё с нуля?

Comment: @I_CaR да не слушайте вы фанатиков. прогать надо 

 * на том что подходит
 * на том что удобно

Comment: @eicto будьте добры выбирать выражения, я вас не оскорблял.

Comment: >А на чём кодить web-приложения надо? Pithon учить? опять всё с нуля?

можно подумать, вы php не с нуля учите

Comment: @DreamChild а меня может оскорбляет неуважение к сообществу php, в выражениях "докатиться".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

я, конечно, не эксперт в php, но по-моему, вы в вашем цикле нигде не меняете значение ни для $first_id_rec, ни для $last_id_rec, поэтому цикл получается бесконечным

Answer (score 0):

вот какую кучу пришлось скодить:

```
if (($first_id_rec+7) < $last_id_rec)
    {
    do 
    {
        mysql_query ("DELETE FROM $userstable WHERE `ID` =('$first_id_rec');", $db);
        $result3 = mysql_query ("SELECT `id`, `tabldate` FROM $userstable", $db);           
        $first_id_rec = mysql_result($result3,0,0);         
    }
    while (($first_id_rec+7) < $last_id_rec);
    }
```

Действительно в паскале всё проще-простого!

Comment: обычно пишут просто 

    while (условие) {
      тело
    }

:)

Comment: потому-что
http://www.php.su/learnphp/cs/?cycles#do-while

Comment: я уж забыл о конструкциях типа repeat until :) очень давно ничего подобного не требовалось