# MySQL записывает вверх таблицы!

Tags: mysql

Доброго всем.
Я тут пишу страничку для автоматики на плеер.
И удаляю старые записи даты. ([код тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/209823/php-while-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA))
Всё работает, но почему-то запрос "***INSERT INTO $userstable (`tabldate`) VALUES('$vdate')***"
подставляет не в конец таблицы строку, а в самое её начало!
Это путает мой алгоритм. Почему так происходит?
Таблица создана с "***PRIMARY KEY (id), (id ASC)***"

Comment: Не совсем понятно. Если в таблице есть записи, к примеру 5 штук, то, скорее всего `id` последней записи будет 5, а первой - 1. И что, если делать `INSERT` следующей записи, то каков будет ее `id` - минус 1 или 0? :) Если все же 6, то скорее всего вьюер таблицы в GUI сортирует так, что последняя запись видна выше остальных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

СУБД записывает записи не так как вам кажется, если хотите видеть нужный вам порядок используйте ключевое слово ORDER BY в запросе.
На то и созданы СУБД чтобы скрыть от вас реализацию хранения ваших данных и предоставить простой интерфейс для управления вашими данными